# How could I verify created addon without making a website

Tags: credentials

I hired freelancer to create a youtube addon.
The addon works create expect that I have limited API requests I can make.
To increase it seems I have to include Privacy and Policy Link and homepage link.
Is there some kind of general websites URL's I could use for open source projects, which Google would accept?

Freelancer suggested me to create .io site which is free.
But the Google credentials page doesn't accept those.
https://whitevo.github.io/youtubeAddon/

Addon code is available in: (assuming I did everything right to open source the code)
https://github.com/whitevo/youtubeAddon
and
git clone https://whitevo@bitbucket.org/whitevo/youtube-addon.git

I would like to get the addon verified so I could add more videos at once with it.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had to add the domain to Authorized domains list before I could add URL Links.
Domain name had to be written like this: whitevo.github.io/